# ERR conversion from string to type 'double' is not valid. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a label name annual it display number from table in the database , this number is displayed like this 27.9828272.

I want just the 2 decimals.

I tried

```
If FrmLogin.CBformState.Text = "User" Then
    com1.CommandText = "select * from balance where UserID = '" & FrmLogin.txtUserName.Text & "'"
    com1.Connection = cn1

    dr2 = com1.ExecuteReader

    If dr2.Read Then
        Dim b As Double
        annual.Text = b
        b = Math.Round(b, 2)
        FirstName.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(0)).ToString() & "'"
        sick.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(1)).ToString() & "'"
        Maternety.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(2)).ToString() & "'"
        floating.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(3)).ToString() & "'"
        b = "'" & LCase(dr2(4)).ToString() & "'"
        Comptime.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(5)).ToString() & "'"

    End If
```

any help?????????????????????

Comment: You declare `b` as `Double` and then you assign a string to it? Check your syntax again.

Comment: As an aside, your code is fine to learn your way around but you should be aware that it contains a SQL injection vulnerability and shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: can we modify my code just for one label its name annual

Comment: Please put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code or set it in your project's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Label.Text = String.Format("{0:0}", b)
```

Will take the number (b) and display it in the label rounded to 0 decimal places, if that's what you mean?

Also, get into the habit of using OO principles, not procedural ones (eg insftead of `LCase(Blah)` do `Blah.ToLower()`. Then you'll be learning the .Net Framework, not VB.Net helper methods.

Finally, and most importantly, make sure you turn `Option Strict` on in project settings. It will force you to use the correct data types but it makes learning easier and gives you ~30% performance boost. Do not code with this setting off.

Edit: Some clarification re: `String.Format`...

```
Dim Number = 12345.6789
String.Format("{0}", Number) '12345.6789
String.Format("{0:#,##0}", Number) '12,345
String.Format("{0:0.0}", Number) '12345.7
String.Format("{0:0.00}", Number) '12345.68
String.Format("{0:000,000.00}", Number) '012,345.68

'You can also combine multiple variables...
Dim Number 2 = 10
String.Format("{0}: {1}", Number, Number2) '12345.6789: 10
```

Ok, editing your code...

```
If dr2.Read Then
    Dim MyNumber = 12345.6789

    annual.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", MyNumber) '' <-- Setting a string variable (`.Text`) with a number fails. Use the formatted string instead...
    FirstName.Text = String.Format("'{0}'", dr2(0).ToLower())
    sick.Text = String.Format("'{0}'", dr2(1).ToLower())
    Maternety.Text = String.Format("'{0}'", dr2(2).ToLower())
    floating.Text = String.Format("'{0}'", dr2(3).ToLower())
    'Not sure what you're trying to do here but `b` was a Double and you're trying to set it to a string. If you just want the number do. See below.
    b = "'" & LCase(dr2(4)).ToString() & "'" 
    Comptime.Text = "'" & LCase(dr2(5)).ToString() & "'"
End If
```

If you have a string containing a number ("123.456") like the one from the database, you can convert it to a double as follows:

```
Dim InputString = "123.456"
Dim MyNumber = Double.Parse(InputString)
```

If you want to format a number as a string for display, that's when you use the `String.Format` I mentioned above.

Incidentally, instead of using `Dim` without an `As` (which means create a variable and determine what type it is from how I use it), use specific types until you're familiar with them. Then you'll have a better mental/visual representation of what you're trying to store where...

Also, since you're putting quotes around all your variables, it would make sense to factor that out into a different method...

```
Public Function QuoteLower(Input as String) As String
    Return String.Format("'{0}'", Input.ToLower())
End Function
```

Then `Maternety.Text = String.Format("'{0}'", dr2(2).ToLower())` would become `Maternety.Text = QuoteLower(dr2(2))`

**Be Warned:** Quoting strings never works reliably. There are too many edge-cases and someone malicious will be able to exploit your code (What happens when someone's surname is `O'Connelly` or when they type SQL into your form?). Really you want to be using Parameterised Queries or an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) framework. The most common ones in .Net are the Entity Framework and nHibernate. Something to bear in mind for next time.

Comment: Thanks for the advising  ,, sorry i am not professional at VB.net Still beginner  i did the following but still the same error  i want to display the number in the label as 27.23

Comment: I've added some more examples to explain how String Formatting works. Can you give the exact exception message you're getting? (And which line of code)

Comment: Note: Your initial error says "From string to double", so somewhere in your code, you're trying to store a string in a double. Without knowing which line, it's hard to identify the problem.

Comment: Either you have a compile time error (likely) or a run time error (possible). If it's a compile-time error, it will be listed in the View->Error List menu option, with a lien number. Double-click to go to line. If it's runtime, the program will stop and it will highlight the line causing the problem. I'd have a go at editing your code but without your database (and a much better idea of what you're trying to do) I'd only be guessing

Comment: I did Put it in an Answer ,,,and no error in the error list ,,,its box show the error ,

Comment: See my edits, does that help clarify things?. Incidentally, if you have more info, please edit your question and add it in, rather than posting an "Answer". I'll flag for someone to tidy up those you've already created. Nothing to worry about, just that we work a little differently to most forums.

Comment: Glad I could help. Welcome to SO. Good luck!